# Android GPS works on tablet, it doesn't on smartphone

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm trying to create and draw the route from the current device position to a defined destination.
When i test the app on a Tablet, it works well. But when i test it on smartphone, it crashes.
Here's the code that i wrote:

```
                    public class RoutePath extends MapActivity {
                        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
                        MapView mapView;
                        private RoutePath _activity;
                        GeoPoint srcGeoPoint,destGeoPoint;
                        private static List<Overlay> mOverlays;
                        MapController mc;
                        Location location;
                        private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
                        String n;
                        double longitude;
                        double latitude;


                        @Override
                        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                            ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
                            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar));

                            SharedData data = SharedData.getInstance();
                            mapView = new MapView(this,"***MAP KEY*****");
                            mapView.setClickable(true); 




                            setContentView(mapView);
                            _activity = this;
                            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
                            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);//work with network
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();

                            double src_lat = latitude;
                            double src_long = longitude;
                            double dest_lat = 38.1267303;
                            double dest_long = 13.3466097;

                           String n = String.valueOf(src_long);
                           Log.d("asd",n);

                            if(src_lat == -1 || src_long == -1 || dest_lat == -1 || dest_long == -1){
                                showAlert("Please enter source and destination points");
                            }else{

                                srcGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (src_lat * 1E6),(int) (src_long * 1E6));
                                destGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (dest_lat * 1E6),(int) (dest_long * 1E6));

                                List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                                Drawable srcdrawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin1);
                                CustomItemizedOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(srcdrawable);
                                //CustomItemizedOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(getDrawable("com/agarwal/route/pin_green.png"));
                                OverlayItem srcoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(srcGeoPoint, "Hello!", "This is your Location.");

                                Drawable destdrawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin1);
                                CustomItemizedOverlay  destitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay( destdrawable );
                               // CustomItemizedOverlay destitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(getDrawable("com/agarwal/route/pin_red.png"));
                                OverlayItem destoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(destGeoPoint, "Hello!", "This is dest Location.");

                                srcitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(srcoverlayitem);
                                destitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(destoverlayitem);

                                mapOverlays.add(srcitemizedOverlay);
                                mapOverlays.add(destitemizedOverlay);

                                connectAsyncTask _connectAsyncTask = new connectAsyncTask();
                                _connectAsyncTask.execute();       
                                mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                                mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
                                mOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                                mapView.getController().animateTo(srcGeoPoint);
                                mapView.getController().setZoom(12);
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return false;
                        }
                        //era private prima di 
                       private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
                            private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
                            @Override
                            protected void onPreExecute() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                super.onPreExecute();

                                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(_activity);
                                progressDialog.setMessage("Caricamento del percorso...");
                                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                                progressDialog.show();
                            }
                            @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                fetchData();

                                return null;
                            }
                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                super.onPostExecute(result);           
                                if(doc!=null){
                                    Overlay ol = new MyOverlay(_activity,srcGeoPoint,srcGeoPoint,1);
                                    mOverlays.add(ol);
                                    NodeList _nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("status");
                                    Node node1 = _nodelist.item(0);
                                    String _status1  = node1.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                                    if(_status1.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){
                                        NodeList _nodelist_path = doc.getElementsByTagName("overview_polyline");
                                        Node node_path = _nodelist_path.item(0);
                                        Element _status_path = (Element)node_path;
                                        NodeList _nodelist_destination_path = _status_path.getElementsByTagName("points");
                                        Node _nodelist_dest = _nodelist_destination_path.item(0);
                                        String _path  = _nodelist_dest.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                                        List<GeoPoint> _geopoints = decodePoly(_path);
                                        GeoPoint gp1;
                                        GeoPoint gp2;
                                        gp2 = _geopoints.get(0);
                                        Log.d("_geopoints","::"+_geopoints.size());
                                        for(int i=1;i<_geopoints.size();i++) // the last one would be crash
                                        {

                                            gp1 = gp2;
                                            gp2 = _geopoints.get(i);
                                            Overlay ol1 = new MyOverlay(gp1,gp2,2,Color.BLUE);
                                            mOverlays.add(ol1);
                                        }
                                        Overlay ol2 = new MyOverlay(_activity,destGeoPoint,destGeoPoint,3);
                                        mOverlays.add(ol2);

                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }else{
                                        showAlert("Unable to find the route");
                                    }

                                    Overlay ol2 = new MyOverlay(_activity,destGeoPoint,destGeoPoint,3);
                                    mOverlays.add(ol2);
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    mapView.scrollBy(-1,-1);
                                    mapView.scrollBy(1,1);
                                }else{
                                    showAlert("Unable to find the route");
                                }

                            }

                        } //end Async
                        Document doc = null;
                        private void fetchData()
                        {

                            StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
                            urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=");
                            urlString.append( Double.toString((double)srcGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
                            urlString.append(",");
                            urlString.append( Double.toString((double)srcGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
                            urlString.append("&destination=");//to
                            urlString.append( Double.toString((double)destGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
                            urlString.append(",");
                            urlString.append( Double.toString((double)destGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
                            urlString.append("&sensor=true&mode=driving");    
                            Log.d("url","::"+urlString.toString());
                            HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null;
                            URL url = null;
                            try
                            {
                                url = new URL(urlString.toString());
                                urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                                urlConnection.connect();
                                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                                doc = (Document) db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());//Util.XMLfromString(response);
                            }catch (MalformedURLException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }catch (IOException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }catch (ParserConfigurationException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            catch (SAXException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        private List<GeoPoint> decodePoly(String encoded) {

                            List<GeoPoint> poly = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
                            int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
                            int lat = 0, lng = 0;

                            while (index < len) {
                                int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
                                do {
                                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                                    shift += 5;
                                } while (b >= 0x20);
                                int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                                lat += dlat;

                                shift = 0;
                                result = 0;
                                do {
                                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                                    shift += 5;
                                } while (b >= 0x20);
                                int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                                lng += dlng;

                                GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (((double) lat / 1E5) * 1E6),
                                        (int) (((double) lng / 1E5) * 1E6));
                                poly.add(p);
                            }

                            return poly;
                        }
                        private void showAlert(String message){
                            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(_activity);
                            alert.setTitle("Error");
                            alert.setCancelable(false);
                            alert.setMessage(message);
                            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }
                            });
                            alert.show();
                        }


                        private Drawable getDrawable(String fileName){
                            return Drawable.createFromStream(_activity.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName), "pin");
                        }


                    }
```

I guess that the problem could be the high RAM's use, because im' trying to create a route between two places away over 1200 km, and so the tablet RAM can bear this process, but not the smartphone.
The Android version that i'm using to test is 4.0.3, both on the tablet than on smartphone.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If your question is about a crash, you should post a log with a stack trace.

Comment: i'm testing directly on device, not with the emulator, and the device is not linked with USB. I got no LogCat.

Comment: You can get logs later using `adb logcat -d <filename>`. Also, depending on the way your app functions, you could potentially use an emulator and spoof GPS coordinates using the Emulator Control part of Android Device Monitor (also it's in the DDMS perspective in Eclipse).